# Linking buttons to imported information from csv file

Tags: csv, button, processing

I would like to ask some help turning this representation into something more interactive. Im working with Processsing latest version. The main idea is I have a table in excel, I imported it into processsing. So far so good. Displayed the values as bubbles. My problem is that  would like to create buttons to See further details from each bubble. So, click a button A, the corresponding bubbleA would light up and display its specific value, according to the imported table. I dont know how to connect the button to each bubble, neither how to turn the bubble to its original state once the button is pressed again.

I`m not from the programming field, I just manage to get this far with info that I have found online, so the code must be pretty messed up. I was trying to use the libraries from Processing but I cant really understand how the controlP5 works.. I asssume the structure is way more advanced than what I can handle now. 
So, if anyone can help me, I would appreciate it very much.

```
Table B_A_table;
//Bubble[] bubbles = new Bubble[29];
ArrayList<Bubble> bubbles = new ArrayList<Bubble>();
float scale = 3;
int c_verdeClaro = color(182,189,149);
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
PFont font;
PFont font1;


void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  colorMode(HSB,255);
  loadData();
  font = createFont("Verdana", 18);
  font1 = createFont("Verdana Bold", 18);
  //font = loadFont("Arial-Black-48.vlw");
//BEGIN TEST 
cp5 = new ControlP5(this);


  noStroke();
  smooth();

//TEST

cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  ButtonBar b = cp5.addButtonBar("bar")
     .setPosition(500, 0)
     .setSize(400, 20)
     .addItems(split("Man Woman 20s 30s 40s 50s µµ½É±Ç"," "))
     ;
     println(b.getItem("Man"));
  b.changeItem("a","text","first");
  b.changeItem("b","text","second");
  b.changeItem("c","text","third");
  b.onMove(new CallbackListener(){
    public void controlEvent(CallbackEvent ev) {
      ButtonBar bar = (ButtonBar)ev.getController();
      println("hello ",bar.hover());

    }
  });






//WND TEST 


}

void draw() {

  // Display all bubbles
  background(0);
    Graph_Bike_Aware_Experience_Sim();
  //Graph_Bike_Uso_Satisf();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(400,500);
      for (Bubble bubble : bubbles){
    bubble.display();
  }
    popMatrix();
    }



void loadData() {
  // "header"  indicates the file has header row. The size of the array 
  // is then determined by the number of rows in the table. 
  B_A_table = loadTable("BikeAwareExpr_Nao.csv", "header");
  for (int i = 0; i<B_A_table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    // Iterate over all the rows in a table.
    TableRow row = B_A_table.getRow(i);
    // Access the fields via their column name (or index).
    float x = row.getFloat("awareness_x")*scale;
    float y = row.getFloat("experi")*scale;
    float d = row.getFloat("awareness_x")*0.2;
    String n = row.getString("Awareness_Bike");
    Float id = row.getFloat("ID");
    // Make a Bubble object out of the data from each row.
    bubbles.add(new Bubble(x, y, d, n,id));
    //bubbles[i] = new Bubble(x, y, d, n);
  }
}

// This simple Bubble class draws a circle to the window 
// and displays a text label when the mouse hovers.
class Bubble {
  float x, y;
  float diameter;
  String name;
  Float id;

  // Create the Bubble
  Bubble(float tempX, float tempY, float tempD, String s, Float id) {
    x = tempX;
    y = tempY;
    diameter = tempD;
    name = s;
  }

  // Display the Bubble
  void display() {
    stroke(220);
    strokeWeight(1);
    noFill();
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    fill(200);
    textFont(font,15);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    text(name, x,y);

  }
}

void Graph_Bike_Aware_Experience_Sim(){
  pushMatrix();
  int tam_table = B_A_table.getRowCount();
  translate(400,500);
  stroke(150);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line( - 100 *scale, 0*scale, + 100*scale, 0*scale);
  line(0*scale,  - 100*scale, 0*scale, + 100*scale);
  //fill(c_verdeClaro);
  noStroke();

  fill(255);
  textFont(font,13);
  text("Experience", 40 , -97*scale);
  text("Awareness", -89*scale, -10);
  fill(50);
  //textFont(Arial-Black-48, 32);
  text("0", 10,15);
  pushMatrix();
  fill(0);
  textFont(font1,30 );
  text("IDEAL", 80*scale , -120*scale);
  fill(70);
  textFont(font1,25 );
  text("Bicycle", 0 , -110*scale);
  popMatrix();
popMatrix();

}
/*void Graph_Bike_Uso_Satisf(){
  pushMatrix();
  int tam_table = B_A_table.getRowCount();
  translate(900,400);
  stroke(150);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line( - 100 *scale, 0*scale, + 100*scale, 0*scale);
  line(0*scale,  - 100*scale, 0*scale, + 100*scale);
  //fill(c_verdeClaro);
  noStroke();
  c_verdeClaro_grad();
  c_verdeEscuro_grad();
  c_Vermelho_grad();



  fill(255);
  text("Experience", 40 , -97*scale);
  text("Awareness", -89*scale, -10);
  fill(0);
  //textFont(Arial-Black-48, 32);
  text("word", 10, 50);
  text("IDEAL", 97*scale , -97*scale);
  popMatrix();

}
*/
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and focus on one small step at a time. If you get stuck, please post a [mcve]. Good luck.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for letting me know .

Answer (score 0):

To handle this without Object Oriented Programing, or 'OOP' is a waste of time and code.

But relax OOP also referred to as "Objects" or " Classes". It is not that hard to get. In fact it is simple to learn, I mean, the basic stuff. And it makes things very easy.

In your case, you need to build an object to represent your data. Then you create several of them, populate with data, and all will be hold together. Kind of knowing it own business.

The usual example is

Class car

has those properties

color

plate

Then you can say:

- Make a Blue, 3231 car!
- Make a Red, 3001 car!

and so on...

When you need it you can ask, Blue car what's your plate, and it will know.

They can also have kind of "behaviours" known as functions or methods. Those do things, so you could say: "Red, turn right", or "Bubble, show me your data!" and they will OBEY you. :)

There is no point in trying to teach this hear though. There are TONs of great tutorials around. Use Duck Duck Go :) or google if you like.

This one [here](https://processing.org/tutorials/objects/) are from [Processing's tutorials section](https://processing.org/tutorials/) itself. Great ones to begin with. :)